# maximal ideals of polynomial ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

For a maximal ideal $n$ of a polynomial ring $ R [x]  $ over a commutative ring $R$  with identity, are there conditions under which $m [x]\subset n$, for some maximal ideal $m$ of $R$?

Note: $m [x] $ is the ideal of $R [x] $, generated by $m $.

For example, if $R $ is a zero dimensional ring it is true.

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to $m\subset n\cap R$ ; equivalently, it means that $n\cap R$ (which is a prime ideal of $R$) is maximal. This holds in particular if $R$ is a *Jacobson ring*, that is, every prime ideal is an intersection of maximal ideals; every finitely generated algebra over a field or over $\mathbb{Z}$ is a Jacobson ring. For all of this see for instance EGA I, §6.4.

Comment: @ abx: Did you mean $n\cap R$ or $n\cap R[x]$?

Comment: Oups! That was $n\cap R$ of course, thanks. I edit.